# Importing theano.shared

Tags: theano

These three imports work:

```
from theano import tensor
import theano.tensor
from theano import shared
```

But this one doesn't:

```
import theano.shared
```

instead, there's this error message:

> ImportError: No module named shared

Comment: `import theano.shared` won't work as `shared` is not a module, its a function.